# ReOrdering Cell Items sorted by Date in a Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have the following code that reorders items in a table view by pressing and holding then moving the items to a different location as shown in the image attached.

The code works perfectly for a objects that are ordered by index paths.

My model has changed though and now orders the items by date. Any ideas on how i can modify the code to change to re-assign dates to cells that are swapped so they are saved in core data.

```
//MARK : - Cell Re-Ordering
    struct Drag {
        static var placeholderView: UIView!
        static var sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!
        static var sourceDate: NSDate!
    }

func handleLongPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let point = gesture.locationInView(tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)

    switch gesture.state {
    case .Began:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
            Drag.sourceIndexPath = indexPath

            var center = cell.center
            Drag.placeholderView = placeholderFromView(cell)
            Drag.placeholderView.center = center
            Drag.placeholderView.alpha = 0

            tableView.addSubview(Drag.placeholderView)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
                center.y = point.y
                Drag.placeholderView.center = center
                Drag.placeholderView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
                Drag.placeholderView.alpha = 0.95

                cell.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { (_) in
                    cell.hidden = true
            })

        }
    case .Changed:
        guard let indexPath = indexPath else {
            return
        }

        var center = Drag.placeholderView.center
        center.y = point.y
        Drag.placeholderView.center = center

        if indexPath != Drag.sourceIndexPath {

            /////////////// Swap the Index Path ///////////////
            swap(&self.weekDayModel.exerciseItems[indexPath.row], &self.weekDayModel.exerciseItems[Drag.sourceIndexPath.row]) //Previous Model Swapping
            tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(Drag.sourceIndexPath, toIndexPath: indexPath)
            Drag.sourceIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    default:
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(Drag.sourceIndexPath) {
            cell.hidden = false
            cell.alpha = 0

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
                Drag.placeholderView.center = cell.center
                Drag.placeholderView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                Drag.placeholderView.alpha = 0
                cell.alpha = 1
                }, completion: { (_) in
                    Drag.sourceIndexPath = nil
                    Drag.placeholderView.removeFromSuperview()
                    Drag.placeholderView = nil
            })
        }
    }
}

func placeholderFromView(view: UIView) -> UIView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let snapshotView : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
    snapshotView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    snapshotView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    snapshotView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0, 0.0)
    snapshotView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    snapshotView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    return snapshotView
}
```

My Core Data Model:

```
import CoreData
@objc(graduationModel)
class graduationModel: NSManagedObject {

    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
extension graduationModel {

    @NSManaged var Name: String?
    @NSManaged var graduation: String?

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?

}
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: ok.. you have to add an attribute in your DB say rank/order for each item/row. Once your are going to move/change with any cell(row) then also replace rank of each others between them.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS That could work. I'm just not sure how I would keep track of the rank/order attribute in creating the next object. On adding a new item then I will have to know the last created rank/order attribute to prevent conflicting order/rank attributes. Might be a little tougher than using dates unless you know a better way around that problem. ;)

Comment: Makes sense. @SwiftArchitect. Is your suggestion in line with previous comment - Adding a rank attribute for each entity in model or do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**Sort Core Data Objects**

- What comes out of Core Data are `NSSet`, i.e. unordered objects. Trade off for speed I suppose. You can only sort by attributes you have made available to you.
- Change the model and reflect the new order in the UI, rather than changing the UI and hope to propagate to Core Data. Using a `NSFetchResultController` will handle all the UI refresh: all you need to pay attention to is your Core Data integrity.

**Model**

You can only sort using attributes associated to your object. Consider using incremental unique identifiers, creation `NSDate`, modification `NSDate`, all will help you in sorting your content later.

**User Interface**

Greatly reduce your work by leveraging `NSFetchedResultsController`.

---

An example of sorting using both proper model and `NSFetchedResultsController` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11600712/218152).