# Core Data update result values

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to save in coreData an object list on moveRowAt. I am saving my data in a singleton and it is well ordered but when I update on Core Data it's never saved and the order is wrong.

[image: This is my list, I moved first item to 4 position] [image: Singleton ordered]

```
func changeKrakenPosition(source: Int, destiny: Int){

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        var results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        var source = source
        var destiny = destiny
        var destinyItem = results[destiny]
        var sourceItem = results[source]

        if source < destiny {
            var dif = destiny - source
            for i in 0...dif {
                if i != dif {
                    var krakenCoreDataToMove = results[source+1]
                    results[source] = krakenCoreDataToMove
                    source += 1
                } else {
                    results[source] = destinyItem
                }
            }
            results[destiny] = sourceItem
        } else if destiny < source {
            var dif = source - destiny
            for i in 0...dif {
                if i !=  dif{
                    var krakenCoreDataToMove = results[source-1]
                    results[source] = krakenCoreDataToMove
                    source -= 1
                } else {
                   results[source] = destinyItem
                }
            }
            results[destiny] = sourceItem
        } else {
            //Moved to same position
        }

        var resultKra = results as! [Kraken]
        for res in resultKra {
            print("name:  \(res.name) age \(res.age)")
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            //Handle Error
        }

    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }

}
```

[image: first time ordering Core Data]

for the first time it works well but never saved, i enter again and I move the new first item to the last position and this is what happens

[image: its like i haven't done the first movement]

saving in CoreData i think would solve the problem but any help or solution would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know exactly what do you want to do, but by the way, you can order your array easily with.

```
struct CustomObject{
    let i: Int
    let j: String
}

var array: [CustomObject] = [
    CustomObject(i: 1, j: "1"),
    CustomObject(i: 0, j: "0"),
    CustomObject(i: 3, j: "3"),
                            ]

let newArray = array.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    first.i < second.i
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the order solution, what i want to do i to save the new results ordered into context and keep my data, i don't know if I have to modify the results array fetched or i have to do something else but I can't save into Core Data

Comment: Please, check this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600571/what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-core-data-entity